# Building a website without hosting?

Tags: wordpress, server, dns, hosting, web-hosting

I just took over a website for a client. I can access the wordpress backend to build and manage the site, but when I log into GoDaddy is says nothing about being hosted. Can anyone give me insight on this topic?

Comment: It is probably managed WordPress hosting, they host the whole installation of WordPress giving you access to it, but you don't have phpMyAdmin, cPanel and similar.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a situation where you might FTP in an upload the files that way. See if it has FTP support.

If so, download Filezilla (freeware) and login to the IP address with your username and password for the site. If you get in, you can upload and overwrite files that way and they should be live instantly.

I also recommend calling or using the online chat function of GoDaddy. They can probably tell you how to manage the site.